# Python decoding JSON

Tags: python, json

I have a JSON file that gets generated and I'm trying to write a python script where it can read the JSON file and once a condition is met activate a routine on a PI.
However, I'm having troubles reading the JSON file in python for the data I need.

The JSON file looks like this:

```
{
    "TimestampEpoch": 1514337528024,
    "StationLat": -26.358342,
    "StationLon": 120.620019,
    "SoftwareVersion": "1.9.0.8120",
    "DetectorModel": "LD-350",
    "AntennaAlignment": 0,
    "StrikeCount": 55,
    "StormCount": 0,
    "StrikeData": [{
        "time": 29639,
        "millis": 1514333639000,
        "dist": 439,
        "bng": 332.70000000000005,
        "lat": -22.823276496341727,
        "lon": 118.65980333825893,
        "type": 0,
        "polarity": 0,
        "compoundType": 0,
        "correlated": true,
        "NMEAChecksum": 255
    }, {
        "time": 29975,
        "millis": 1514333975000,
        "dist": 436,
        "bng": 339.5,
        "lat": -22.6637997412206,
        "lon": 119.13533272287572,
        "type": 0,
        "polarity": 0,
        "compoundType": 0,
        "correlated": true,
        "NMEAChecksum": 255
    }, {
        "time": 30051,
        "millis": 1514334051000,
        "dist": 529,
        "bng": 336.5,
        "lat": -21.964135129972036,
        "lon": 118.57970482593052,
        "type": 0,
        "polarity": 1,
        "compoundType": 1,
        "correlated": true,
        "NMEAChecksum": 255
    }, {
        "time": 30053,
        "millis": 1514334053000,
        "dist": 548,
        "bng": 341.90000000000003,
        "lat": -21.646237895040606,
        "lon": 118.97714953741881,
        "type": 0,
        "polarity": 0,
        "compoundType": 0,
        "correlated": true,
        "NMEAChecksum": 255
    }, {
        "time": 30074,
        "millis": 1514334074000,
        "dist": 666,
        "bng": 358.3,
        "lat": -20.347305744621128,
        "lon": 120.43114211954078,
        "type": 0,
        "polarity": 0,
        "compoundType": 0,
        "correlated": false,
        "NMEAChecksum": 255
    }, {
        "time": 30091,
        "millis": 1514334091000,
        "dist": 451,
        "bng": 338.3,
        "lat": -22.5661850362272,
        "lon": 118.9997657520629,
        "type": 0,
        "polarity": 1,
        "compoundType": 1,
        "correlated": true,
        "NMEAChecksum": 255
    }, {
        "time": 30213,
        "millis": 1514334213000,
        "dist": 445,
        "bng": 340.70000000000005,
        "lat": -22.559589456858671,
        "lon": 119.19103156558813,
        "type": 0,
        "polarity": 0,
        "compoundType": 0,
        "correlated": true,
        "NMEAChecksum": 255
    }, {
        "time": 30338,
        "millis": 1514334338000,
        "dist": 527,
        "bng": 342.90000000000003,
        "lat": -21.802954792173065,
        "lon": 119.12298209450069,
        "type": 0,
        "polarity": 1,
        "compoundType": 1,
        "correlated": true,
        "NMEAChecksum": 255
    }, {
        "time": 30395,
        "millis": 1514334395000,
        "dist": 517,
        "bng": 344.70000000000005,
        "lat": -21.850074765420533,
        "lon": 119.30160949216324,
        "type": 0,
        "polarity": 0,
        "compoundType": 0,
        "correlated": true,
        "NMEAChecksum": 255
    }, {
        "time": 30411,
        "millis": 1514334411000,
        "dist": 439,
        "bng": 335.70000000000005,
        "lat": -22.735547655819584,
        "lon": 118.86244538684973,
        "type": 1,
        "polarity": 1,
        "compoundType": 2,
        "correlated": true,
        "NMEAChecksum": 255
    }, {
        "time": 30465,
        "millis": 1514334465000,
        "dist": 435,
        "bng": 340.70000000000005,
        "lat": -22.645118167469189,
        "lon": 119.22223589812695,
        "type": 0,
        "polarity": 0,
        "compoundType": 0,
        "correlated": true,
        "NMEAChecksum": 255
    }, {
        "time": 30474,
        "millis": 1514334474000,
        "dist": 426,
        "bng": 338.6,
        "lat": -22.769695914648562,
        "lon": 119.10739796460815,
        "type": 0,
        "polarity": 1,
        "compoundType": 1,
        "correlated": true,
        "NMEAChecksum": 255
    }, {
        "time": 30517,
        "millis": 1514334517000,
        "dist": 422,
        "bng": 343.20000000000005,
        "lat": -22.706276839927302,
        "lon": 119.4336531844265,
        "type": 0,
        "polarity": 0,
        "compoundType": 0,
        "correlated": true,
        "NMEAChecksum": 255
    }, {
        "time": 30550,
        "millis": 1514334550000,
        "dist": 502,
        "bng": 341.3,
        "lat": -22.057012959363277,
        "lon": 119.0621863925286,
        "type": 1,
        "polarity": 0,
        "compoundType": 2,
        "correlated": true,
        "NMEAChecksum": 255
    }, {
        "time": 30568,
        "millis": 1514334568000,
        "dist": 626,
        "bng": 0.70000000000000007,
        "lat": -20.706484302115673,
        "lon": 120.69331598591792,
        "type": 1,
        "polarity": 0,
        "compoundType": 2,
        "correlated": false,
        "NMEAChecksum": 255
    }, {
        "time": 30619,
        "millis": 1514334619000,
        "dist": 429,
        "bng": 341.90000000000003,
        "lat": -22.671184630446479,
        "lon": 119.32400123250297,
        "type": 1,
        "polarity": 1,
        "compoundType": 2,
        "correlated": true,
        "NMEAChecksum": 255
    }, {
        "time": 30740,
        "millis": 1514334740000,
        "dist": 482,
        "bng": 334.1,
        "lat": -22.429482567996327,
        "lon": 118.57644968246939,
        "type": 0,
        "polarity": 1,
        "compoundType": 1,
        "correlated": true,
        "NMEAChecksum": 255
    }, {
        "time": 30802,
        "millis": 1514334802000,
        "dist": 509,
        "bng": 343.40000000000003,
        "lat": -21.947598119246557,
        "lon": 119.21367843405182,
        "type": 0,
        "polarity": 0,
        "compoundType": 0,
        "correlated": true,
        "NMEAChecksum": 255
    }, {
        "time": 30932,
        "millis": 1514334932000,
        "dist": 501,
        "bng": 357.8,
        "lat": -21.838265205726479,
        "lon": 120.43417373312407,
        "type": 0,
        "polarity": 0,
        "compoundType": 0,
        "correlated": false,
        "NMEAChecksum": 255
    }, {
        "time": 30987,
        "millis": 1514334987000,
        "dist": 504,
        "bng": 352.40000000000003,
        "lat": -21.846516520942281,
        "lon": 119.97585623802213,
        "type": 0,
        "polarity": 0,
        "compoundType": 0,
        "correlated": true,
        "NMEAChecksum": 255
    }, {
        "time": 31061,
        "millis": 1514335061000,
        "dist": 532,
        "bng": 339.6,
        "lat": -21.845403176401145,
        "lon": 118.82793102850755,
        "type": 0,
        "polarity": 1,
        "compoundType": 1,
        "correlated": true,
        "NMEAChecksum": 255
    }, {
        "time": 31095,
        "millis": 1514335095000,
        "dist": 476,
        "bng": 338.40000000000003,
        "lat": -22.35275623240533,
        "lon": 118.92019795058822,
        "type": 0,
        "polarity": 0,
        "compoundType": 0,
        "correlated": true,
        "NMEAChecksum": 255
    }, {
        "time": 31096,
        "millis": 1514335096000,
        "dist": 461,
        "bng": 340.8,
        "lat": -22.420408704787498,
        "lon": 119.14858320666184,
        "type": 1,
        "polarity": 1,
        "compoundType": 2,
        "correlated": true,
        "NMEAChecksum": 255
    }, {
        "time": 31125,
        "millis": 1514335125000,
        "dist": 543,
        "bng": 333.70000000000005,
        "lat": -21.944786037307939,
        "lon": 118.29322928909902,
        "type": 1,
        "polarity": 0,
        "compoundType": 2,
        "correlated": true,
        "NMEAChecksum": 255
    }, {
        "time": 31151,
        "millis": 1514335151000,
        "dist": 456,
        "bng": 353.70000000000005,
        "lat": -22.265499884683305,
        "lon": 120.13493890271367,
        "type": 1,
        "polarity": 1,
        "compoundType": 2,
        "correlated": true,
        "NMEAChecksum": 255
    }, {
        "time": 31163,
        "millis": 1514335163000,
        "dist": 554,
        "bng": 345.3,
        "lat": -21.513872273875773,
        "lon": 119.26477299490306,
        "type": 0,
        "polarity": 0,
        "compoundType": 0,
        "correlated": true,
        "NMEAChecksum": 255
    }, {
        "time": 31187,
        "millis": 1514335187000,
        "dist": 461,
        "bng": 334.5,
        "lat": -22.589028884800324,
        "lon": 118.69130961855463,
        "type": 0,
        "polarity": 0,
        "compoundType": 0,
        "correlated": true,
        "NMEAChecksum": 255
    }, {
        "time": 31190,
        "millis": 1514335190000,
        "dist": 461,
        "bng": 345.6,
        "lat": -22.322829802559983,
        "lon": 119.5081430161772,
        "type": 0,
        "polarity": 0,
        "compoundType": 0,
        "correlated": true,
        "NMEAChecksum": 255
    }, {
        "time": 31211,
        "millis": 1514335211000,
        "dist": 450,
        "bng": 341,
        "lat": -22.510056831175177,
        "lon": 119.19713605692327,
        "type": 0,
        "polarity": 1,
        "compoundType": 1,
        "correlated": true,
        "NMEAChecksum": 255
    }, {
        "time": 31221,
        "millis": 1514335221000,
        "dist": 529,
        "bng": 347.3,
        "lat": -21.694740285215946,
        "lon": 119.49738343680414,
        "type": 0,
        "polarity": 0,
        "compoundType": 0,
        "correlated": true,
        "NMEAChecksum": 255
    }, {
        "time": 31236,
        "millis": 1514335236000,
        "dist": 543,
        "bng": 349.70000000000005,
        "lat": -21.531761761814693,
        "lon": 119.68393479671597,
        "type": 0,
        "polarity": 0,
        "compoundType": 0,
        "correlated": true,
        "NMEAChecksum": 255
    }, {
        "time": 31250,
        "millis": 1514335250000,
        "dist": 533,
        "bng": 348.5,
        "lat": -21.639083078219766,
        "lon": 119.59467921262058,
        "type": 1,
        "polarity": 0,
        "compoundType": 2,
        "correlated": true,
        "NMEAChecksum": 255
    }, {
        "time": 31339,
        "millis": 1514335339000,
        "dist": 526,
        "bng": 357.70000000000005,
        "lat": -21.612952163347568,
        "lon": 120.4163746302582,
        "type": 0,
        "polarity": 0,
        "compoundType": 0,
        "correlated": false,
        "NMEAChecksum": 255
    }, {
        "time": 31344,
        "millis": 1514335344000,
        "dist": 526,
        "bng": 335,
        "lat": -22.038453902384596,
        "lon": 118.46863480066909,
        "type": 0,
        "polarity": 0,
        "compoundType": 0,
        "correlated": true,
        "NMEAChecksum": 255
    }, {
        "time": 31344,
        "millis": 1514335344000,
        "dist": 539,
        "bng": 347.1,
        "lat": -21.610104095695242,
        "lon": 119.45917399508555,
        "type": 0,
        "polarity": 1,
        "compoundType": 1,
        "correlated": true,
        "NMEAChecksum": 255
    }, {
        "time": 31391,
        "millis": 1514335391000,
        "dist": 536,
        "bng": 332.1,
        "lat": -22.061375971933707,
        "lon": 118.19224364927328,
        "type": 0,
        "polarity": 0,
        "compoundType": 0,
        "correlated": true,
        "NMEAChecksum": 255
    }, {
        "time": 31402,
        "millis": 1514335402000,
        "dist": 543,
        "bng": 348.8,
        "lat": -21.545588955773745,
        "lon": 119.60303835252884,
        "type": 0,
        "polarity": 0,
        "compoundType": 0,
        "correlated": true,
        "NMEAChecksum": 255
    }, {
        "time": 31508,
        "millis": 1514335508000,
        "dist": 460,
        "bng": 342.70000000000005,
        "lat": -22.387187628113903,
        "lon": 119.29270963231856,
        "type": 0,
        "polarity": 0,
        "compoundType": 0,
        "correlated": true,
        "NMEAChecksum": 255
    }, {
        "time": 31920,
        "millis": 1514335920000,
        "dist": 547,
        "bng": 344,
        "lat": -21.603736403856253,
        "lon": 119.16555944440349,
        "type": 0,
        "polarity": 1,
        "compoundType": 1,
        "correlated": true,
        "NMEAChecksum": 255
    }, {
        "time": 32050,
        "millis": 1514336050000,
        "dist": 558,
        "bng": 343.6,
        "lat": -21.517402635433793,
        "lon": 119.10118425525948,
        "type": 0,
        "polarity": 1,
        "compoundType": 1,
        "correlated": true,
        "NMEAChecksum": 255
    }, {
        "time": 32071,
        "millis": 1514336071000,
        "dist": 563,
        "bng": 342.8,
        "lat": -21.493685086667679,
        "lon": 119.01530105404373,
        "type": 0,
        "polarity": 1,
        "compoundType": 1,
        "correlated": true,
        "NMEAChecksum": 255
    }, {
        "time": 32072,
        "millis": 1514336072000,
        "dist": 560,
        "bng": 344.5,
        "lat": -21.479020325404111,
        "lon": 119.17768587022923,
        "type": 0,
        "polarity": 0,
        "compoundType": 0,
        "correlated": true,
        "NMEAChecksum": 255
    }, {
        "time": 32089,
        "millis": 1514336089000,
        "dist": 471,
        "bng": 335.90000000000003,
        "lat": -22.464740290545972,
        "lon": 118.75276302335249,
        "type": 0,
        "polarity": 0,
        "compoundType": 0,
        "correlated": true,
        "NMEAChecksum": 255
    }, {
        "time": 32101,
        "millis": 1514336101000,
        "dist": 481,
        "bng": 302,
        "lat": -24.001746592394504,
        "lon": 116.61161165846737,
        "type": 0,
        "polarity": 1,
        "compoundType": 1,
        "correlated": false,
        "NMEAChecksum": 255
    }, {
        "time": 32312,
        "millis": 1514336312000,
        "dist": 514,
        "bng": 295.8,
        "lat": -24.266914385503728,
        "lon": 116.06272864500153,
        "type": 1,
        "polarity": 0,
        "compoundType": 2,
        "correlated": false,
        "NMEAChecksum": 255
    }, {
        "time": 32328,
        "millis": 1514336328000,
        "dist": 736,
        "bng": 2.8000000000000003,
        "lat": -19.72000669424304,
        "lon": 120.96222291627785,
        "type": 0,
        "polarity": 1,
        "compoundType": 1,
        "correlated": false,
        "NMEAChecksum": 255
    }, {
        "time": 32427,
        "millis": 1514336427000,
        "dist": 515,
        "bng": 295,
        "lat": -24.320304717886881,
        "lon": 116.02149565519926,
        "type": 0,
        "polarity": 0,
        "compoundType": 0,
        "correlated": false,
        "NMEAChecksum": 255
    }, {
        "time": 32439,
        "millis": 1514336439000,
        "dist": 569,
        "bng": 335.8,
        "lat": -21.655160674908917,
        "lon": 118.36906830000049,
        "type": 0,
        "polarity": 1,
        "compoundType": 1,
        "correlated": true,
        "NMEAChecksum": 255
    }, {
        "time": 32478,
        "millis": 1514336478000,
        "dist": 532,
        "bng": 297.3,
        "lat": -24.080840483434571,
        "lon": 115.97134537670488,
        "type": 0,
        "polarity": 1,
        "compoundType": 1,
        "correlated": false,
        "NMEAChecksum": 255
    }, {
        "time": 32791,
        "millis": 1514336791000,
        "dist": 477,
        "bng": 305.7,
        "lat": -23.795622841783853,
        "lon": 116.81980755479187,
        "type": 0,
        "polarity": 0,
        "compoundType": 0,
        "correlated": false,
        "NMEAChecksum": 255
    }, {
        "time": 33090,
        "millis": 1514337090000,
        "dist": 669,
        "bng": 347.70000000000005,
        "lat": -20.450062973111823,
        "lon": 119.2565952488157,
        "type": 0,
        "polarity": 1,
        "compoundType": 1,
        "correlated": false,
        "NMEAChecksum": 255
    }, {
        "time": 33099,
        "millis": 1514337099000,
        "dist": 525,
        "bng": 350.8,
        "lat": -21.67704264192249,
        "lon": 119.80987551646857,
        "type": 1,
        "polarity": 1,
        "compoundType": 2,
        "correlated": false,
        "NMEAChecksum": 255
    }, {
        "time": 33187,
        "millis": 1514337187000,
        "dist": 501,
        "bng": 338.3,
        "lat": -22.144634501719153,
        "lon": 118.82584090050709,
        "type": 0,
        "polarity": 0,
        "compoundType": 0,
        "correlated": false,
        "NMEAChecksum": 255
    }, {
        "time": 33259,
        "millis": 1514337259000,
        "dist": 500,
        "bng": 303.90000000000003,
        "lat": -23.783521377777497,
        "lon": 116.54893498720863,
        "type": 0,
        "polarity": 1,
        "compoundType": 1,
        "correlated": false,
        "NMEAChecksum": 255
    }, {
        "time": 33476,
        "millis": 1514337476000,
        "dist": 524,
        "bng": 297.8,
        "lat": -24.080259854117323,
        "lon": 116.06210416089792,
        "type": 0,
        "polarity": 0,
        "compoundType": 0,
        "correlated": false,
        "NMEAChecksum": 255
    }],
    "StormData": []
}
```

My Python Script is

```
import urllib 
import json
f = urllib.urlopen("http://mysite/lightningdata/ngxarchive.json")
values = json.load(f)
f.close()

for StrikeData in values['StrikeData']:
for key, value in StrikeData.iteritems():
    print key, 'is:', value
print ''
```

When I run this script, I get my data laid out in a readable format and it's all there - now I only want to read "dist" under "StrikeData" and have a condition to only list distances below 40. This is where I'm struggling. For the life of me I can't even get python to just print the "dist" keys infact I can't get it to print any keys that reside under "StrikeData"

However, I can read other keys above "StrikeData" such as "StationLon" "StationLat" etc.

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: Your indenting looks off - is this the exact code you're running?

Comment: And btw, you can get your json data as a python dict if you just use the requests module instead. `resp = requests.get("http://mysite/lightningdata/ngxarchive.json")` gives you your response. `resp.json` is a nice dict you can iterate through.

Comment: `value['dist']` is what you want.

Comment: You have a condition to only lists distances bellow 40. There are no distances less than 400. Is that your problem? See what happens when you change/remove the condition. Can you show us what your condition is?

Comment: Abs - do you mean indenting for the Python code? then ye this is how it looks.

i'm very new to python so not sure how to use the resp.json call but i'll look into it. 

Barmar - value['dist'] doesn't give me anything it errors out - as mentioned anything under "StrikeData" i cant seem to call.

SCB - i haven't added the condition in yet for the 40 distance but thats what i want to achieve once i can call the dist data

Comment: Are you sure `StrikeData['dist']` doesn't work?

Comment: @blurp - when i change this line of code: `code for StrikeData in values['dist']: ` i get the following error:

for StrikeData in values['dist']:
KeyError: 'dist'

Comment: That's not what is being suggested here. In your original `for` loop, try `StrikeData['dist']`.

Comment: what about trying `for StrikeData in values['StrikeData']['dist']`

Comment: @Blurp - thank you - this pointed me in the right direction and now i'm getting the results i need

Comment: And without fixing the indentation?

Comment: No - i had to fix the indentation as well as pointed out by Abs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The distance should be in `StrikeData['dist']`:

```
for StrikeData in values['StrikeData']:
    print 'Distance is: ', StrikeData['dist']
```

[DEMO](https://ideone.com/gbU89t)

If you only want to show distances below 40, it would be:

```
for StrikeData in values['StrikeData']:
    if StrikeData['dist'] < 40:
        print 'Distance is: ', StrikeData['dist']
```

But none of the data in your sample JSON meets this criteria, so nothing would be printed.

Comment: thank you Barmar this works too - something simple in the end - i appreciate all the feedback